# Dynamic Names in Kendo DateRangePicker

Tags: javascript, datetime, kendo-ui, momentjs

I have a Kendo daterangepicker defined like this:

```
    $('#range').daterangepicker(
    {
        ranges: {
            'Today': [moment(), moment()],
            'Yesterday': [moment().subtract('days', 1), moment().subtract('days', 1)],
            'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 6), moment()],
            'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 29), moment()],
            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
            'Last Month': [moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'), moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')]
        },
        startDate: moment().subtract('days', 29),
        endDate: moment()
    },
    function(start, end) {
        $('#startDate').val(start.format('M/D/YYYY'));
        $('#endDate').val(end.format('M/D/YYYY'));
        refreshFileList();
    }
).prev().on("click", function() {
    $(this).next().focus();
});
```

How can I change "Today", "Yesterday", etc to be values read in from a variable rather than hard coded in the Javascript. For example:

```
var oneMonth = "One Month";

    $('#range').daterangepicker(
    {
        ranges: {
            oneMonth : [moment().subtract('month', 1), moment()],
            threeMonths: [moment().subtract('month', 3), moment()],
            sixMonths: [moment().subtract('month', 6), moment()],
            allMonths: [moment().subtract('year', 15), moment()]
        },
        startDate: moment().subtract('month', 3),
        endDate: moment()
    },
    function (start, end) {
        $('#startDate').val(start.format('M/D/YYYY'));
        $('#endDate').val(end.format('M/D/YYYY'));
        refreshThumbnails();
    }).prev().on("click", function () {
    $(this).next().focus();
});
```

When I do like above, instead of displaying the value of oneMonth ("One Month"), it displays the variable name ("oneMonth") in the date range picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic property names based on a variable value, you will use bracket notation.

Create a data object prior to the range specification.  Use object bracket notation to add a dynamic property name to the object.  Use the object for the property of the ranges option.

```
oneMonthLabel = "One Month";

myranges = {};
myranges[oneMonthLabel] = [moment().subtract('month', 1), moment()];

$('#range').daterangepicker(
...
    ranges: myRanges,
```

If you don't need to set the property based on a variable just use a quoted property name.

```
    ranges: {
        "One month" : [moment().subtract('month', 1), moment()],
        "3 months": [moment().subtract('month', 3), moment()],
        "6 months": [moment().subtract('month', 6), moment()],
        "All months": [moment().subtract('year', 15), moment()]
    },
```